# validación cruzada en R con knnVcn crea NA una línea de cada dos

Tags: r, validación

Quiero hacer un validación cruzada con knnVCN y el conjunto de dato `iris`: elimino una linea y intento predecirlo y hizo esto con todas las lineas del conjunto de dato. Sin embargo me da `NA` una línea de cada dos y no sabe porque :

```
install.packages("knnGarden")
install.packages("cluster")
#install.packages("e1071")

library(cluster)
library(knnGarden)
good<-0
for(i in 1:150){
  test <- iris[i,]
  train <- iris[-i,]
  result <- knnVCN(train[,-5], train[,5], test, K = 3, ShowObs=T,"maximum")

  print(result[i,5])
  print(result[i,6])
  if((result[i,5])==(result[i,6])){
    good<-good+1
  }
  print("siguiente ?????????")

}
```

Por ejemplo tengo el siguiente output:

```
[1] setosa
Levels: setosa
[1] setosa
Levels: setosa
[1] "siguiente ?????????"
[1] <NA>
Levels: setosa
[1] <NA>
Levels: setosa
```

Las primeras lineas dan setosa y esta bien : el modelo predice las buenas clases. Sin embargo desde el segundo iteración me da `NÀ.
Pueden ayudarme obetner clases en lugar de`NA`?

Answer (score 1):

Algunas observaciones:

1. Estas testeando por fila, por lo que `result` será un `data.frame` con una sola fila de forma que hacer `result[i,5]` es erróneo, lo correcto es `result[,5]`
2. El otro problema es que `result` no tiene una columna con índice 6, lo que tu quieres en realidad es comparar el valor "real" `iris[i,5]` con el "pronosticado", debieras hacer esto: `if((result[,5])==(as.character(iris[i,5])))`, nota además que debemos convertir el valor a un `character` ya que originalmente es un factor y no funcionaría la comparación

El Script quedaría algo así:

```
library(cluster)
library(knnGarden)
good<-0
for(i in 1:150){
    test <- iris[i,-5]
    train <- iris[-i,]
    result <- knnVCN(train[,-5], train[,5], test, K = 3, ShowObs=T,"maximum")

    if((result[,5])==(as.character(iris[i,5]))){
        good<-good+1
    }
}
print(paste0(good, " aciertos de 150"))
```